# Prestashop - add other inputs to order

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

How can I add 2 more inputs/text areas to order process in prestashop.

In the step with addresses the is also "Note" text area, and here I need add 2 more inputs. 
Add inputs to template is easy, but how can i store information from this inputs in database (for example in ps_orders table)?

I need use this information in invoice and in emails.

Comment: You should add extra fields in the database, add extra fields in the Order Class, and set your extra fields in ParentOrderController